# Android emulator does not complete startup on Macbook Pro (Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970')

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I have been trying to launch an app in the android emulator using Android Studio on Mac OS X Yosemite in a Macbook Pro mid 2010.

When I launch the emulator from within Android Studio it never finishes startup (the screen remains black). So I tried to launch it from the terminal with -debug-all and I noticed that it keeps trying to do this:

```
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
```

I tried with Nexus 5 API 21 x86 and Galaxy Nexus API 21, and I also disabled Host GPU without success. I also disabled the firewall to rule out network rules issues, but I get the same error.

Any idea of what might be the issue? This is the full log:

```
emulator:Found AVD name 'Galaxy_Nexus_API_21'
emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator:Looking for emulator-x86 to emulate 'x86' CPU
emulator:Probing program: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
emulator:Found target-specific emulator binary: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86
emulator:Probing for: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/libOpenglRender.dylib
emulator:Probing for: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/libOpenglRender.dylib
emulator:Found OpenGLES emulation libraries in /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib
emulator:Setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib
emulator: found SDK root at /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.ini
emulator: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='avd.ini.encoding' VALUE='UTF-8'
emulator:    2: KEY='path' VALUE='/Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd'
emulator:    3: KEY='path.rel' VALUE='avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd'
emulator:    4: KEY='target' VALUE='Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
emulator: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.ini: parsing finished
emulator: virtual device content at /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/config.ini
emulator: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/config.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='avd.ini.encoding' VALUE='UTF-8'
emulator:    2: KEY='AvdId' VALUE='Galaxy_Nexus_API_21'
emulator:    3: KEY='abi.type' VALUE='x86'
emulator:    4: KEY='avd.ini.displayname' VALUE='Galaxy Nexus API 21'
emulator:    5: KEY='disk.dataPartition.size' VALUE='200M'
emulator:    6: KEY='hw.accelerometer' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    7: KEY='hw.audioInput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    8: KEY='hw.battery' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    9: KEY='hw.camera.back' VALUE='none'
emulator:   10: KEY='hw.camera.front' VALUE='none'
emulator:   11: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='x86'
emulator:   12: KEY='hw.dPad' VALUE='no'
emulator:   13: KEY='hw.device.hash2' VALUE='MD5:6930e145748b87e87d3f40cabd140a41'
emulator:   14: KEY='hw.device.manufacturer' VALUE='Google'
emulator:   15: KEY='hw.device.name' VALUE='Galaxy Nexus'
emulator:   16: KEY='hw.gps' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   17: KEY='hw.gpu.enabled' VALUE='no'
emulator:   18: KEY='hw.keyboard' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   19: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='320'
emulator:   20: KEY='hw.mainKeys' VALUE='no'
emulator:   21: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='1024'
emulator:   22: KEY='hw.sdCard' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   23: KEY='hw.sensors.orientation' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   24: KEY='hw.sensors.proximity' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   25: KEY='hw.trackBall' VALUE='no'
emulator:   26: KEY='image.sysdir.1' VALUE='system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86/'
emulator:   27: KEY='runtime.network.latency' VALUE='none'
emulator:   28: KEY='runtime.network.speed' VALUE='full'
emulator:   29: KEY='runtime.scalefactor' VALUE='auto'
emulator:   30: KEY='sdcard.path' VALUE='/Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/sdcard.img'
emulator:   31: KEY='skin.dynamic' VALUE='no'
emulator:   32: KEY='skin.name' VALUE='galaxy_nexus'
emulator:   33: KEY='skin.path' VALUE='/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources/galaxy_nexus'
emulator:   34: KEY='snapshot.present' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   35: KEY='tag.display' VALUE='Google APIs'
emulator:   36: KEY='tag.id' VALUE='google_apis'
emulator:   37: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='64'
emulator: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/config.ini: parsing finished
emulator: using core hw config path: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found target field in root AVD .ini file: 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:21'
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 21
emulator:     found image search path: system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86/
emulator: found a total of 1 search paths for this AVD
emulator: found build.prop in search dir: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86/
emulator: Read property file at /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//build.prop
emulator:     no boot.prop in search dir: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86/
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: found skin 'galaxy_nexus' in directory: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources
emulator: autoconfig: -skin galaxy_nexus
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources
emulator: no skin-specific hardware.ini in /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CALL to F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HANGUP to F4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HOME to Home
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_BACK to Escape
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to PageUp
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to Shift-F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to PageDown
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_POWER to F7
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_SEARCH to F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-Keypad_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to Keypad_Plus
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to Ctrl-F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to Keypad_Minus
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to Ctrl-F6
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_NETWORK to F8
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACING to F9
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_FULLSCREEN to F9
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER to Keypad_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_UP to Keypad_8
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT to Keypad_4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT to Keypad_6
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN to Keypad_2
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACKBALL to F6
emulator: adding binding SHOW_TRACKBALL to F6
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to Keypad_7
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to Ctrl-F11
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to Keypad_9
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to Ctrl-F12
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_UP to Keypad_Multiply
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_DOWN to Keypad_Divide
emulator: keyset loaded from: /Users/mymacuser/.android/default.keyset
emulator: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/emulator-user.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='window.x' VALUE='0'
emulator:    2: KEY='window.y' VALUE='23'
emulator:    3: KEY='uuid' VALUE='1419171378365'
emulator: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/emulator-user.ini: parsing finished
emulator: trying to load skin file '/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources/galaxy_nexus/layout'
emulator: found kernel-qemu in search dir: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86/
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//kernel-qemu
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires legacy device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: found ramdisk.img in search dir: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86/
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: found system.img in search dir: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86/
emulator: Using initial system image: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1024MB

emulator:     no qwerty2.kcm in search dir: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86/
emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: HAX (version 2) is installed and usable.
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing as .ini file
emulator: <memoryFile>: parsing finished
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.cpu.model = qemu32
  hw.ramSize = 1024
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = no
  hw.trackBall = no
  hw.keyboard = yes
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = no
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  hw.sdCard.path = /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 720
  hw.lcd.height = 1280
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 320
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.initialOrientation = portrait
  hw.camera.back = none
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 64
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  hw.useext4 = yes
  kernel.path = /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = no
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img

  disk.systemPartition.size = 750m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 550m
  avd.name = Galaxy_Nexus_API_21
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86"
emulator: argv[01] = "-netspeed"
emulator: argv[02] = "full"
emulator: argv[03] = "-netdelay"
emulator: argv[04] = "none"
emulator: argv[05] = "-enable-hax"
emulator: argv[06] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[07] = "/Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator64-x86 -netspeed full -netdelay none -enable-hax -android-hw /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service hw-control
emulator: android_hw_control_init: hw-control qemud handler initialized
emulator: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/hardware-qemu.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='hw.cpu.arch' VALUE='x86'
emulator:    2: KEY='hw.cpu.model' VALUE='qemu32'
emulator:    3: KEY='hw.ramSize' VALUE='1024'
emulator:    4: KEY='hw.screen' VALUE='touch'
emulator:    5: KEY='hw.mainKeys' VALUE='no'
emulator:    6: KEY='hw.trackBall' VALUE='no'
emulator:    7: KEY='hw.keyboard' VALUE='yes'
emulator:    8: KEY='hw.keyboard.lid' VALUE='no'
emulator:    9: KEY='hw.keyboard.charmap' VALUE='qwerty2'
emulator:   10: KEY='hw.dPad' VALUE='no'
emulator:   11: KEY='hw.gsmModem' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   12: KEY='hw.gps' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   13: KEY='hw.battery' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   14: KEY='hw.accelerometer' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   15: KEY='hw.audioInput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   16: KEY='hw.audioOutput' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   17: KEY='hw.sdCard' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   18: KEY='hw.sdCard.path' VALUE='/Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/sdcard.img'
emulator:   19: KEY='disk.cachePartition' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   20: KEY='disk.cachePartition.path' VALUE='/Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/cache.img'
emulator:   21: KEY='disk.cachePartition.size' VALUE='66m'
emulator:   22: KEY='hw.lcd.width' VALUE='720'
emulator:   23: KEY='hw.lcd.height' VALUE='1280'
emulator:   24: KEY='hw.lcd.depth' VALUE='16'
emulator:   25: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='320'
emulator:   26: KEY='hw.lcd.backlight' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   27: KEY='hw.gpu.enabled' VALUE='no'
emulator:   28: KEY='hw.initialOrientation' VALUE='portrait'
emulator:   29: KEY='hw.camera.back' VALUE='none'
emulator:   30: KEY='hw.camera.front' VALUE='none'
emulator:   31: KEY='vm.heapSize' VALUE='64'
emulator:   32: KEY='hw.sensors.proximity' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   33: KEY='hw.sensors.magnetic_field' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   34: KEY='hw.sensors.orientation' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   35: KEY='hw.sensors.temperature' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   36: KEY='hw.useext4' VALUE='yes'
emulator:   37: KEY='kernel.path' VALUE='/Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//kernel-qemu'
emulator:   38: KEY='kernel.parameters' VALUE='androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1'
emulator:   39: KEY='kernel.newDeviceNaming' VALUE='no'
emulator:   40: KEY='kernel.supportsYaffs2' VALUE='no'
emulator:   41: KEY='disk.ramdisk.path' VALUE='/Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img'
emulator:   42: KEY='disk.systemPartition.initPath' VALUE='/Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//system.img'
emulator:   43: KEY='disk.systemPartition.size' VALUE='750m'
emulator:   44: KEY='disk.dataPartition.path' VALUE='/Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/userdata-qemu.img'
emulator:   45: KEY='disk.dataPartition.size' VALUE='550m'
emulator:   46: KEY='avd.name' VALUE='Galaxy_Nexus_API_21'
emulator: /Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/hardware-qemu.ini: parsing finished
emulator: Using kernel serial device prefix: ttyS
emulator: Ramdisk image contains fstab.goldfish file
emulator: Found format of system partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of userdata partition: 'ext4'
emulator: Found format of cache partition: 'ext4'
emulator: system partition format: ext4
emulator: Mapping 'system' partition image to /tmp/android-mymacuser/emulator-py27T0
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0x2ee00000,file=/tmp/android-mymacuser/emulator-py27T0,initfile=/Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-21/google_apis/x86//system.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: userdata partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0x22600000,file=/Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/userdata-qemu.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: cache partition format: ext4
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/Users/mymacuser/.android/avd/Galaxy_Nexus_API_21.avd/cache.img,pagesize=512,extrasize=0
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service boot-properties
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '64m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '320'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gsm
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service gps
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'none'
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service camera
emulator: android_camera_service_init: Registered 'camera' qemud service
emulator: IP address of your DNS(s): 192.168.1.1
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator:     trying to find: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 0.431831
emulator: android_qemud_init
emulator: Registered QEMUD service sensors
emulator: android_hw_sensors_init: sensors qemud service initialized
emulator: Forcing ro.adb.qemud to "0".
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Using config file: /Users/mymacuser/.android/modem-nv-ram-5554
Setting value of oper_name_index to 2 (2)Setting value of selection_mode to 0 (0)Setting value of oper_index to 0 (0)Setting value of oper_count to 2 (2)Setting value of in_ecbm to 0 (0)Setting value of prl_version to 0 (0)Setting value of preferred_mode to 15 (15)Setting value of cdma_subscription_source to 1 (1)Setting value of cdma_roaming_pref to 2 (2)emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /Users/mymacuser/Library/Android/sdk/tools/ddms ping emulator standalone "NVIDIA Corporation" "NVIDIA GeForce 320M OpenGL Engine" "2.1 NVIDIA-10.0.19 310.90.10.05b12"
emulator: EVENT: kEventMouseMotion x=475 y=330 xrel=475 yrel=330 button=0

emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
emulator: Error while connecting to socket '127.0.0.1:1970': 61 -> Connection refused
emulator: ASC 127.0.0.1:1970: Retrying connection. Connector FD = 30
```

Comment: It looks like the emulator is nearly up.  What happens if you try to connect with ADB (adb shell)?  Have you tried adb kill-server?

Comment: I tried `adb kill-server` but it seems to have no visible effect. I also tried `./adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.example.geoquiz/com.example.geoquiz.QuizActivity` but I got
    `error: device offline`. The device even gets mouse events when I move my mouse over the emulator `emulator: EVENT: kEventMouseMotion x=475 y=330 xrel=475 yrel=330 button=0`

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, I'm afraid.  I've had all sorts of trouble with the x86 versions of the emulators, though never this exact problem.  Your emulator is very close to being up.  If adb sees the device as off-line, though, you can't even use logcat to diagnose it.  Be sure you have given the HAXM driver more memory than you are giving the emulator...

Comment: ... you might, also, check your configuration.  My emulator runs at port 5554...

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you eventually solve it ?

Comment: Hi Zabojad, unfortunately I could not find a solution. I had to use a real phone instead of an emulator.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late, but I have something to say about this issue.

Seems the kernel which comes together with the SDK tries by default to find a multi-touch device. I have the same problem, and I tried to open a TCP socket at 127.0.0.1:1970, by issuing:

```
nc -l 1970
```

A this point I launched the emulator with the following options:

```
-verbose -debug all -show-kernel
```

and got a message from SDKCtl multi-touch about trying to establish an handshake with some device on the incriminated socket.

This led me to think about the need for a multi-touch device (I don't know in what way). So I looked for the options about the touch screen, and found that the touch screen is by default enabled as multi-touch (this is reported somewhere in the emulator outputs). To have it behaving as a simple touch-screen, one needs to add the following option when invoking the emulator:

```
-screen touch
```

At this point the emulator does not try to connect to 127.0.0.1:1970 anymore.

I add that in my case, even leaving the multi-touch on, the emulator was able to boot (after a long time - and this is true also without multi-touch).